# How to get all files URL at once?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase Storage to save music. I'm trying to get all files from the Storage to get all URLs? (I'm uploading files manually).

I'm getting a specific file like this:

```
 private void setdata(){
        progressd.setMessage("Downloadingggg :) --- (:");
        progressd.show();
        storageRef.child("mmp/smile.mp3").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
                final DatabaseReference newsong = mMusicdata.push();
                newsong.child("music").setValue(uri.toString());
                progressd.dismiss();

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                // Handle any errors
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "nooooooooooooooooo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progressd.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
```

But I want to get all files at once.

How can I run a query for all the files? Get the URL and save it to Firebase Database? Thanks.

Comment: this doesn't look like javascript at all

Comment: First, you should learn correct capitalization rules.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this is a question not english lesson :)

Comment: @WaseemHa your question will be more likely to receive an answer if you follow common English conventions.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in [my comment to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42671713/how-to-retrieve-mp3-files-from-firebase-storage): there is no public API in Firebase Storage to list the files.

If you're uploading them manually, you could also manually add them to a list in the database.

Alternatively you could [install the gcloud tools](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install) and [use `gsutil` to get a list of the files](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/ls):

```
gsutil ls gs://<your-project>.appspot.com
```